# Multi tenancy with Merb, DataMapper and CouchDB (or MongoDB)

Tags: couchdb, datamapper, multi-tenant, sharding, merb

Does Anyone know to achieve, or have any resources about, muti tenancy involving these technologies?

Additionally, is it recommendable to store sensitive data in a relational database and other kinds of data in NoSQL databases?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Cloudant has been providing multitenancy clusters for a few years now. The technology is based on CouchDB but with a bunch of enhancements. Once you outgrow the multitenant cluster you can "hit a button" and flip over to a private cluster, all of which Cloudant will manage for you.

Feel free to reach out to me offline if you want more info or check out http://www.cloudant.com.

I'm less familiar with the hosting options for those other technologies, so I wouldn't feel good about recommending one. In full disclosure I work at Cloudant, but I often recommended them before they hired me. :)

Cheers.